# how to get max of values by row and colmun in sql

Tags: sql

Table has values

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
```

we need to show data maximum of row-wise and column-wise.

Result should be

```
RowWiseMax, ColumnWiseMax
30, 70
60, 80
90, 90
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, better explain the logic.  Why are "30" and "70" paired together in the same row in the result set?

Comment: explain how you get 30,70 in first row and 60,80 in second row instead of 60,70.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 30 is the max value on the first row and 70 is the max value on the first column. Looks like a matrix.

Comment: if we check this like matrix then there would be 9 rows in output.

Comment: Add one more _row_ with sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: @GG.  . . . I see now reason why the first row should be paired with the first column.

Comment: Can we assume your rows always have exactly three columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to the puzzle as presented, I've had to make the assumption that the number of columns is not dynamic, this solution works using T-Sql, it's not clear what your database platform is but should hopefully port if different. Using a table named "T" with columns c1, c2, c3

```
select RowWiseMax,
    case Row_Number() over (order by RowWiseMax)
    when 1 then Max(c1) over()
    when 2 then Max(c2) over()
    when 3 then Max(c3) over()
    end ColumnWiseMax
from T
cross apply (
    select Max(v) RowWiseMax 
    from (values (c1), (c2), (c3))v(v)
)x
```